# Website building. Elements added by script not showing, but then show after a refresh

Tags: javascript, html, loading

I have this strange... error? Unwanted behaviour.
I add some div elements via script. If you've never visited the site before, it will not load any of those divs. I see that because all of those divs have a background-image property set. I also know I actualy add them well because when I refresh the page, I see the result that I want to see. So, the problem is that when someone comes to that website firs time, he'll see nothing. No "buttons" (those are the divs I was talking about), and he doesn't know he needs to refresh the page to see them like I do.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="outter">
        <script> CreateButton('outter','','','right', 'kolica'); </script>

        <div id="menu"></div>
        <script>
            CreateButton('menu','','','left', 'menuBtnNovo');
            CreateButton('menu','','','left', 'menuBtnDzidzabidze');
            CreateButton('menu','','','left', 'menuBtnUskoro');
            CreateButton('menu','','','left', 'menuBtnPredlozi');
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

**SCRIPT** (edit)

```
<script>
        function CreateButton(parentElementID, width, height, floating, id){
            // create div
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.Id = id;
            div.style.float = floating;
            div.style.padding = "0";
            div.style.margin = "0";
            div.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
            div.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/mo/" + id + ".png)";
            div.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/def/" + id + ".png)";

            var imageSrc = div.style.backgroundImage.replace(/url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi, '$2').split(',')[0];
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = imageSrc;

            if(width ==  '') width =  image.width +  "px";
            if(height == '') height = image.height + "px";
            div.style.width  = width ;
            div.style.height = height;
            div.onmouseover = function(){ div.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/mo/" +  id + ".png)"; };
            div.onmouseout  = function(){ div.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/def/" + id + ".png)"; };

            // append
            if(parentElementID != '')   document.getElementById(parentElementID).appendChild(div);
            else                        document.body.appendChild(div);
        }
    </script>
```

The script for `CreateButton` is included in the head, and it works fine, just not the first time you go on site. Why is the page not loading them on time? In script, I do append the div to the parent via parentID, and I do all the formating and image loading for that button that I want. I admit that I'm pretty new in HTML and JavaScript.
**Question:** Why don't the divs load on time? How do I overcome this?

Comment: Can you include the CreateButton script?

Comment: Shure. Here it is. But I don't see how it could help

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Walked the code in the debugger to make sure it's being called?

Comment: Try putting the script at the end of the body not in the head.

Comment: nope. doesn't work.

Comment: i run your code locally and after some modifications it works as intended... you might need to access your site and press f12, look into the console tab for errors then post them here...

Comment: Ok, I clear the cash, go to the site, and I have 1 error in console, but I think it's no biggie, + I always get this error. It says: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.index.html